# Titanium post httpclient fail second time

Tags: titanium, httpclient

Stuck with this for several days already. I already google but there is no advice on this. So any help is appreciated a lot. I recently work with posting JSON data to web service Titanium. For example: I made a service to register and unregister a module. First, when I register with this module:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    enableKeepAlive: false
});
xhr.timeout=2000;
xhr.onerror=function(){};

xhr.onload = function(e){
//Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
var response= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
//Ti.API.info(response.err+'  '+response.msg);
if (response.err==0){
        alert(response.msg);
        win.close();
  };         
var link='https://dttc.haui.edu.vn/RegisterSubject';       

xhr.open('POST',link);
var params=({            
  s:Ti.App.Properties.getString('Student_ID',''),
  t:win.trainingid
});
xhr.send(params);
```

It works perfectly. Then I unregister with the same code but in different window with different link, it freeze my app even it does the unregister:

```
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    enableKeepAlive: false
});
xhr.timeout=2000;
xhr.onerror=function(){};

xhr.onload = function(e){
//Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
var response= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
//Ti.API.info(response.err+'  '+response.msg);
if (response.err==0){
        alert(response.msg);
        win.close();
  };         
var link='https://dttc.haui.edu.vn/UnRegisterSubject';       

xhr.open('POST',link);
var params=({            
  s:Ti.App.Properties.getString('Student_ID',''),
  t:win.trainingid
});
xhr.send(params);
```

Please leave any comments if u have any suggestion?

Comment: Does your web address is fully functional? Maybe you can test this by using the address for registering for a course. Edit the values to hardcoded values (e.g. -1) and fire your request. When it works the error most likely occurs on server side.

Comment: The web service is fine. Actually, there is already an android app working by this service. I wrote this app version run on ios by titanium. Cannot understand why the app freezing when I post the data the second time. THe first time work perfectly. Anyway thanks Robin.